# Array not being randomized as it should and values coming in negative

Tags: c, arrays, random, time

I'm trying to store random numbers using the `srand` function to store values in a 2D Array using a loop. When I print out the array it has the same values everytime and the numbers are often in negative values which is strange and also they remain the same even if `srand` function is there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NROW 13
#define NCOL 11

int main()
{
    void disp_array(int a[NROW][NCOL]);

    int ar[NROW][NCOL];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < NROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NCOL; j++) {
            ar[NROW][NCOL] = (rand() % 101);
        }
    }
    disp_array(ar);

    return 0;
}

void disp_array(int a[NROW][NCOL])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("Value at row %d column %d is %d \n", i, j, a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `ar[NROW][NCOL]= (rand()%101);` again. Is that really correct? What element in `ar` are you assigning to?

Comment: Also, don't forget to [seed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) the prng.

Comment: I solved it, I'm such an idiot.

Comment: What do you mean seed the prng?

Comment: `ar[NROW][NCOL]= (rand()%101);` -->
  as  `ar[i][j]= (rand()%101);`

Comment: The seed explanation is on the link on his comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand

Comment: Please post an answer so that others can benefit from your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the statement `ar[NROW][NCOL]= (rand()%101);` is not correct as  every time  you are assigning data into same `ar[NROW][NCOL]` and `NROW` & `NCOL` is not varying.

So Replace it like `ar[i][j]= (rand()%101);`

Secondly, to print array elements, print like this

```
for (i=0;i<NROW;i++){  /* don't use < 5 or < 7 if you have NROW & NCOL*/
        for(j=0;j<NCOL;j++){
               ar[i][j]= (rand()%101);
        }
}
```

Finally, In statement `ar[i][j]= (rand()%101);` `rand()` generates same random number if you don't change the seed value. Read the manual page of `rand()` and `srand()`. for e.g use `srand(getpid())` before calling `rand()`.

```
srand(getpid());/*getpid() returns process id and 
              every time process manager generates different process id*/
```

See this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html and https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand